# Trying to use pkg-config but it not being a registered command

Tags: windows, go, sdl, pkg-config

Ok so I've got my whole Go development environment up under Windows 8, also with MinGW. I'm using the **LiteIde**.

```
C:/Go/bin/go.exe build  [C:/Users/Alyx/Go/Hi]
pkg-config --cflags sdl
exec: "pkg-config": executable file not found in %PATH%
Error: process exited with code 2.
```

But then I get an error for "pkg-config" which at first I didn't have installed. (I'm trying to compile the SDL binding with a test that lists the fullscreen modes)

Then I got it all set up in the C:\MinGW\Bin folder (pkg-config.exe and the extra dll's).

But then it still wouldn't work. Went into CMD typed in its name "not recognized as internal..."

So then I figured I must need to put an environment variable into Windows. I tried %PATH% with the "C:\MinGW\bin" value. Nothing. Then I tried PKG_CONFIG_PATH. Nothing.

So I'm not sure what Environment Variable I need, or if there is any sort of variable I can put into LiteIde. Other than that idk what else to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error, it sounds like your attempt to add `C:\MinGW\bin` to the `%PATH%` variable was unsuccessful.

Make sure you're adding it to the System Environment Variables under `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System`, Click on `Advanced System Settings`, `Advanced` tab, `Environment Variables...` button and edit the `Path` entry under `System variables` (Add `;C:\MinGW\bin` to the end of the existing value). Then restart your shell or IDE to apply the system settings.

If `pkg-config.exe` is in the `C:\MinGW\bin` folder it will be found in `%PATH%`.

Comment: I have installed cygwin. I am able to run pkg-config independently, but when its getting called by go it says pkg-config executable not found. What could be issue here?

Comment: I have found that cygwin places the pkg-config as pkgconf.exe under the C:\Cygwin\bin\ directory. I renamed it to pkg-config.exe and it worked as expected